# What is the difference between Quit and Exit, once closing MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I've been using `quit` command to close MATLAB. However, recently I've found out that `exit` is the same except it saves your `Editor window`, which is really helpful for me.

MATLAB's help for `exit` says:

`It performs the same as quit and takes the same termination options.`

They are the same but I see that they have some differences.

**Q1:** Are there other differences?

**Q2:** Which one should be used to close MATLAB?

Comment: A lot of languages has aliases to different functions, probably by historical reasons switching from one to another during development of the product. In php, for example, `join` and `implode` are the same, `echo` and `print` too. `I've found out that exit is the same except it saves your Editor window, which is really helpful for me` do not see it in docs. You can save from `finish.m` which is called by both of them if exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A2:** Any, their functionality is identical

**A1:** No, there are no documented difference

---

```
2.2 Quitting
============

 -- Built-in Function:  exit ( STATUS )
 -- Built-in Function:  quit ( STATUS )

     Exit the current session. If the optional integer value
     STATUS is supplied, pass that value to the operating system as the exit status.
     The default STATUS value is zero.

 -- Built-in Function:  atexit ( FUNCT )
 -- Built-in Function:  atexit ( FUNCT, FLAG )

     Register a function to be called when exits.  For example,

          function last_words ()                      %% .DEF
                   disp ( "Bye bye" );
          endfunction

          atexit ( "last_words" );                    %% .REG last_words() via atexit()

     will print the message "Bye bye" when session exits.

     The additional argument FLAG will register or unregister FUNCT from
     the list of functions to be called when session exits.  If FLAG is
     true, the function is registered, and if FLAG is false, it is
     unregistered.  For example, after registering the function
     `last_words()' above,

          atexit ( "last_words", false );             %% !REG remove registered FUNCT

     will remove the function from the list and session will not call
     `last_words' when it exits.

     Note that `atexit' only removes the first occurrence of a function
     from the list, so if a function was placed in the list multiple
     times with `atexit', it must also be removed from the list
     multiple times.
```

Comment: Although your direct answers A1 and A2 are fine, the documentation you quote is for Octave, not MATLAB, and is not relevant to the question. For example, there is no such function as `atexit` in MATLAB.